# I am not able to enter Japanese character to MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode

I tried to enter カテゴリ to MySQL, but I get the following

```
1 row(s) affected.
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x82\xAB\xE3\x83\x86...' 
for column 'bloc_name' at row 1
```

I changed Collation to ujis_japanese_ci, but the result is the same.
Can anyone suggest how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Additional note

I created db like this,

```
CREATE TABLE dtb_bloc (
device_type_id int NOT NULL,
bloc_id int  NOT NULL,
bloc_name text,
tpl_path text,
filename varchar(50) NOT NULL,
create_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
update_date timestamp NOT NULL,
php_path text,
deletable_flg smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
PRIMARY KEY (device_type_id, bloc_id),
UNIQUE (device_type_id, filename)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

+++++++++++++++

Additional note:

I am using MAMP, and the details are followings.

PHP Built On    Darwin sokada-macbook.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun 7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Database Version    5.5.9

Database Collation  utf8_general_ci

PHP Version     5.3.6

Web Server  Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6

WebServer to PHP Interface  apache2handler

Comment: What is the exact type of column 'bloc_name' ?

Comment: Mike I updated. Does it have enough info?

Comment: So you are mixing `ujis_japanese_ci`, `utf8_general_ci` and `latin1`. You must pick one encoding and stick to that, it makes things easier. (Latin charsets cannot hold Japanese characters anyway.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I forgot to change the field collation to sjis_japanese_ci. Now it accepts and display Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

Collation only affects sorting, not which characters are allowed in and how they are stored, which is controlled by character set. Read [this chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html) for more understanding. You will most likely want 'ujis' or 'sjis' or 'utf8':

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET ujis COLLATE ujis_japanese_ci;
```

You may also want to invoke this as your first command from the client;

```
SET NAMES ujis COLLATE ujis_japanese_ci
```